# Filter an Observable using Typescript and Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, observable

I'm trying to filter out archived items from a list (observables)

```
this.archived = afDB.list('/users/'+uid+'/archived/',ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(100)).valueChanges();
this.items    = afDB.list('alerts',ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(20)).valueChanges();

// let newItems$ = Observable.from(this.items);
// let archives$  = Observable.of(this.archived);

this.new_items = Observable.combineLatest([ this.items,
  this.archived ]).filter(([items, archived]) => {
  console.log('Arch: '+JSON.stringify(items.id) );

  var item_array =[];
  for(var a in items)
  {
    item_array.push(items[a]);
    for (var b in archived)
    {

      if(items[a].id === archived[b].id)
      {
      // item_array[archived[b].id].remove();


      }
    }//end of b
  }//end of a

  return item_array;

  });
```

Your input would be greatly appreciated.

[Update] I'm inputting two observables - trying to filter and map them then and I expect to receive an observable as output - less and archived (2nd observable) items. I'm them passing this as this.items to the frontend with an | async pipe.

Expected: that archived items would be filtered from the this.items
Actual: Nothing is happening, just the full feed is returned.

[Edited] Heres my datasets

Archived items:
 -L3fvdIPe1K7wtFO-MFR { id: "430118153785650_1182592608538197"}

Items look like:

430118153785650_1183263311804460 {all_clear: true, category: "", created_time: "2018-01-23T18:41:26+0000", id: "430118153785650_1182592608538197", message: "...", title: ""}

(We are comparing the id element in each to filter)

Thanks!
Kieran

Comment: What's the problem you're running into?

Comment: Hi Doug, the code above isn't actually filtering out anything. I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong. I want to filter the items out against the archived items, then return that to the feed. If that makes sense?

Comment: It would be good if you edited the question to be specific about what you're expecting to happen vs. what is actually happening.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference try this

Comment: @DougStevenson - just edited with more details.

Comment: @ChauTran - the comparison seems to work well with the loops and arrays, however the issue seems to be that its not reflecting the difference in observable coming back.